# jQuery Tabs integrate multiple options

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm a complete JavaScript noob. I am using this right now:

```
$(function() {
   $("#tabs").tabs({
      ajaxOptions: {
         error: function(xhr, status, index, anchor) {
            $(anchor.hash).html(
               "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible.");
         }
      }
   });
});
```

Can someone tell me how to also add this option to it:

```
spinner: 'Loading...'
```

Source: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-spinner

Comment: for the loading part you could add it to the  beforeSend:function(){}

Comment: did you try my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap every single tab with `<span>`

```
<li><a href="#tabs-1"><span>Test 1</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2"><span>Test 2</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3"><span>Test 3</span></a></li>
<li><a href="Home/About"><span>Test Ajax</span></a></li>
```

and use the script like this:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    ajaxOptions: {
        error: function(xhr, status, index, anchor) {
            $(anchor.hash).html(
                    "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                    "If this wouldn't be a demo.");
        }
    }
});

$("#tabs").tabs("option", "spinner", 'Retrieving data...');
```

to test it you should make an ajax call with some delay. I've called an MVC action putting the thread in sleep for 2 seconds.